# Downloading input from textarea to server as a file (Django)

Tags: javascript, django, file-upload

I am working on a django project and I have a textarea where user can type text into.

When a user the submit button, I want to get the contents from the textarea to my server as a file.  This file has to be linked to a model through the FileField in django. (I can create a Fileupload button through django forms but here user types into a textarea field so what is the procedure to convert write it to file and save)

What is the simplest possible way to do this (i.e. to save input of textarea at server in form of a file)?

Comment: Don't think of it as a file in the browser. Submit the data either as form or using ajax and do whatever you need to with that text data in your back end ... write to file or database

Comment: Ok so just save text through a form, creating file through python functions and linking it to my model FileField...